# Bootstrap Table combine footer cells

Tags: bootstrap-table

I'm looking for the ability to combine footer cells. I have an issue where data string if sizable length make the cells in the footer to not align with the data.

[image: Example:]

I found this option: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#footerfield
but it only works with server side pagination.  I need to use client side pagination in order for the print plugin to work properly.

Any ideas?